# Showing a list of software with LGPL during boot

Tags: yocto

I remember seeing a list of software components with LGPL licenses during the start up of Linux root file system built with Yocto Project. I can't seem to figure out what enables this, even after going through the [Mega Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html).

```
NOTICE: This file system contains the following GPLv3 packages:
        autoconf
        bash-dev
        bash
        binutils
        cifs-utils
        cpio
        cpp-symlinks
        cpp
        dosfstools
        elfutils
        g++-symlinks
        g++
        gawk-dev
        gawk
        gcc-symlinks
        gcc
        gdb
        gdbc6x
        gdbserver
        gettext-dev
        gettext
        gzip
        libbfd
        libcairo-dbg
        libcairo-perf-utils
        libdw1
        libelf1
        libgdbm-compat4
        libgdbm-dev
        libgdbm4
        libgettextlib
        libgettextsrc
        libgmp-dev
        libgmp10
        libgmpxx4
        libidn11
        libmpc3
        libmpfr4
        libreadline-dev
        libreadline7
        libunistring2
        m4-dev
        m4
        make
        nettle-dev
        nettle
        parted
        python3-pycairo-dev
        python3-pycairo
        which
If you do not wish to distribute GPLv3 components please remove
the above packages prior to distribution.  This can be done using
the opkg remove command.  i.e.:
    opkg remove <package>
Where <package> is the name printed in the list above

NOTE: If the package is a dependency of another package you
      will be notified of the dependent packages.  You should
      use the --force-removal-of-dependent-packages option to
      also remove the dependent packages as well
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer - it's from [arago-gpl-notice](https://github.com/rcn-ee/meta-arago/tree/master/meta-arago-distro/recipes-core/arago-gpl-notice) from meta-arago. It only displays GPLv3 also.